# how to pass array to the function and the get back the value

Tags: perl

Below is a code snippet from a bigger piece of code I am working on, I am getting this error continuously as i try to reference the array in the function @$instanceObjectEnrichment[0]

```
my @providerCloudEnrichment=("Core","Gen-i WAN Services","Physical Provider Connectivity","TEMPLATE");
createAndEnrichInstance($parentClass,$session,$object,@providerCloudEnrichment);

sub createAndEnrichInstance {

        my ($creationClassName,$session,$instanceObjectString,$instanceObjectEnrichment)=@_;
        if(!($session->instanceExists($instanceObjectString))){
                $session->create($instanceObjectString);
        }
        my $instanceObject=$session->object($instanceObjectString);
        print("i am here  ".@$instanceObjectEnrichment[0]."\n");
        if($creationClassName eq 'ProviderCloud'){
                $instanceObject->put(Model =>"@$instanceObjectEnrichment[0]",Vendor =>"@$instanceObjectEnrichment[1]",Description =>"@$instanceObjectEnrichment[2]",Certification => "@$instanceObjectEnrichment[3]");
        }
        elsif($creationClassName eq 'Interface'){
                $instanceObject->put(Model =>@$instanceObjectEnrichment[0],Vendor =>@$instanceObjectEnrichment[1],Description=>@$instanceObjectEnrichment[2],DisplayName=>@$instanceObjectEnrichment[3],DeviceID=>@$instanceObjectEnrichment[4]);
        }
        else {
                print ("Incorrect Class");
        }
}
```

ERROR

```
Can't use string ("Core") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at createUserDefinedConnections.pl line 149, <$udf> line 326.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass it as an **array reference**:

```
createAndEnrichInstance($parentClass,$session,$object,\@providerCloudEnrichment);
```

This

```
createAndEnrichInstance($parentClass,$session,$object,@providerCloudEnrichment);
```

is equivalent to:

```
createAndEnrichInstance($parentClass,$session,$object,"Core","Gen-i WAN Services","Physical Provider Connectivity","TEMPLATE")
```

Also, since it's an array reference, you can change

```
@$instanceObjectEnrichment[0]
```

to be:

```
$instanceObjectEnrichment->[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a **reference** to the array, or create an **anomymous array** and pass a reference to it.

See the [live demo](http://ideone.com/mw02g4).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "First approach: Pass a reference to the array",
  " using the backslash operator:\n";
my @words = ("Practical", "Extraction and", "Reporting", "Language");
print_words(\@words);

print "\nSecond approach: Pass a reference to an anonymous array:\n";
my $words_ref = ["Practical", "Extraction and", "Reporting", "Language"];
print_words($words_ref);

sub print_words {
    my ($words_ref) = @_;
    for (0 .. $#$words_ref) {
        print "$_. ", $words_ref->[$_], "\n";
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
First approach: Pass a reference to the array using the backslash operator:
0. Practical
1. Extraction and
2. Reporting
3. Language

Second approach: Pass a reference to an anonymous array:
0. Practical
1. Extraction and
2. Reporting
3. Language
```